# How to"permanently install" a scripting library into a web?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

Right now I am following a Mojs tutorial, and, having played a little bit with it, I figured out that installing and uninstalling Mojs through npm install and npm uninstall, respectively, doesn't make any difference - if I have a hyperlink

```
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/mojs/latest/mo.min.js"></script>
```

in my html file, the script works, if I remove it - it stops,no matter if I have Mojs installed through npm. How to make any sense of it?

Comment: The script is loaded from `cdn.jsdelivr.net`. It has **nothing** to do with what is going on at your server. What you install via `npm` are the modules that your nodejs will use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node is just a javascript runtime. You use it to run Javascript code outside of the browser. It doesn't automatically put any script files in your html. Node Package Manager (npm) is a helpful tool for getting packages and modules, such as Mojs, but they have to be 'required' in a seperate js file either by using `require` or `import`

If you've ever used Python, think of Node as Python and npm as pip where you have to run pip install before you can 'import' the module.

Using node you can run any js file by typing `node file.js` similar to how you would run a python script using `python file.js`.

When you install a package using `npm install` a node_modules directory is created and a whole bunch of (usually) javascript files are installed there under a folder of the name of the module, so if you want to manually include the files, you should look there to find it.

I suggest this [introduction to Nodejs](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_introduction.htm).

Answer (score 1):

The script tag that you posted is using a url to a cdn (content delivery network (I think)). This means that when it tries to load the script tag, it looks at the url, then fetches the data from the cdn server and returns it to the browser.

The files you are installing via npm are generally not available to your front-end code unless you are using something like webpack or browserify. They will bundle all of the files you are using from node and allow them to be available in the browser.

So, yes, it does make sense that you installing or uninstalling that package is not affecting the app.